# arraylist returning array memory address

Tags: java

I want to read and store data from a txt file to the ArrayList but it returns memory address instead of the array contents

**main.java**

```
student stud = new student(grades);
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("grades.txt"));
ArrayList<student> list = new ArrayList<student>();

while(in.hasNext){

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
grades[i] = in.nextInt();

stud = new student(grades);
list.add(stud);

}

for(student i : list)
System.out.println(i.details() + "\n");
```

**student.java** file

```
private float grades[];

public student(float[] grades) {
this.grades = grades;
}

public float[] details(){
return grades;
}
```

here's what's inside of the **txt** file

```
75
86
96
85
73
```

I tried manipulating the **main.java** and **student.java** file but it still returns a memory address. Any help?

Comment: Arrays.ToString(i.details())

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions: initial capital letters for classes such as `Student`.

Comment: It is not a memory address, it is the identity hashcode of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is here:

- `float[] grades = i.details();`
- `grades.toString()` shows memory position (i.e. default `toString()` implementation)

To print an array to console it's better to use `Arrays.toString(i.details())`.

---

```java
public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Student> students = readStudentsFromFile(new File("grades.txt"));

    for (Student student : students)
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(student.details()));
}

private static List<Student> readStudentsFromFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();

    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            float[] grades = new float[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < grades.length; i++)
                grades[i] = scan.nextFloat();

            students.add(new Student(grades));

        }
    }

    return students;
}

private static class Student {

    private float[] grades;

    public Student(float[] grades) {
        this.grades = grades;
    }

    public float[] details() {
        return grades;
    }
}
```